# Fixed top nav bar changes font weight when text is over html5 video - Issue in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, html5-video

I have a site I'm working on locally that contains a fixed nav bar and a html5 video element underneath with a height of 500px. The menu items in the nav bar have what looks like a font weight reduction or some kind of -webkit-font-smoothing: issue but only when over the video once the video has been scrolled past the nav bar the font returns to the correct weight.

This is only happening in chrome it was happening in Safari too but managed to fix that using font:100%;.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I've been searching for answers all day. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Webkit sometimes has issues with rendering elements in real time when you have a lot happening on the page at once - especially in your JS. Add this to the parent element of your "sticky" navigation in the CSS:

```
/* Change this to your selector */
.someStickyNavParent {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

If you're still running into an issue with the children of that element, you can always use a universal selector.

```
/* Change this to your selector */
.someStickyNavParent * {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also experiencing the same problem, with no solution whatsoever.

Have tried changing the font, but all I have tested are rendered differently if overlaying a video element. Neither I had success with workaround using webkit css properties such as -webkit-font-smoothing or -webkit-text-stroke.

As I a made some search I've found out, it seems to be a known issue regarding Google Chrome.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=74674

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=100666